# How do I group an average (or a sum) by an object id?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to get the average ratings for a certain movie, but the catch is that after I calculate the average for a person, I need to calculate all the average ratings for that movie.

To be more clear I already calculate the average for a person's rating:

`select person_id, movie_id, ((soundtrack_rate + casting_rate + story_rate) / 3) from ratings`

[image]

**I just need an average for all the ratings for each movie**.
For eg you can see in this image that I want **the average of both 858228 (id) movies**.
So the average, **result that I want** in this example would be **0.8** ( *(1 + 0.6) / 2* )

I don't want just a row, I don't any want duplicates.
I tried to add `group by movie_id` but it didn't work.

Comment: `SELECT movie_id, avg(soundtrack_rate + casting_rate + story_rate) / 3) FROM ratings GROUP BY movie_id`

Comment: Thank you, it worked. You can post this as an answer. Can you please also explain what's the difference between ```avg()/count``` and my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT movie_id, (avg(soundtrack_rate + casting_rate + story_rate) / 3) FROM ratings GROUP BY movie_id
```

When you group by `movie_id` instead of your statement; rows are first grouped per movie, then each group calculates its own average which is what you need.